# Method always return empty list

Tags: java, android, list, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using mvp Design pattern in android development and i am using retrofit2 with it ... when i run the function to get me information from a the web it get the information but returns null list

the Response.Body come with response that mean that the code works

the model function

```
    List<SearchDdb> searchResult;
    private Context context;
    public MainModel(Context context){this.context=context;}
    public List<SearchDdb> searchUser(String name) {
        final MainPresenter presenter = new MainPresenter(context);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        Db db = retrofit.create(Db.class);
        Call<List<SearchDdb>> call = db.getUsers(name);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SearchDdb>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<SearchDdb>> call, Response<List<SearchDdb>> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    presenter.showDialog();
                }
               searchResult = response.body();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<SearchDdb>> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
        return searchResult;
    }
```

the SearchDdb file

```
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String grade;
    private String age;
    private String address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

How i call the function 
`List<SearchDdb> ressult = presenter.searchUser("1");`

Comment: can you explain more sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant call it like `List<SearchDdb> ressult = presenter.searchUser("1");` because `searchUser` method makes an async request via retrofit. This way `searchUse` returns null `searchResult` because response has not come yet.

Define a `LiveData` in your viewmodel class and observe it in your activity/fragment. When response comes from api in 
`onResponse` in `searchUser` post that response to live data and use it where you observe.

If you want to see a tutorial you can look at [this article](https://medium.com/@saquib3705/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-with-the-help-of-mvvm-dagger-livedata-and-rxjava2-in-67aebefe031d).

Here is [another example](https://github.com/faranjit/live-score).

Comment: I made a question and answer specifically for these types of questions :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android